# Como obter a diferença entre datas em dias uteis e fim de semana no javascript

Tags: javascript

Preciso construir uma aplicação que faz o check-in em um hotel, o valor da diária de seg a sex é x e fim de semana é y. Gostaria de saber como eu faço esse cálculo quando houver dias da semana e do fim de semana misturados.

Estou usando o Date para pegar os dias que foram selecionados no calendário, e um for para ver quantos dias o usuário ficou hospedado, mas não consigo saber se houve finais de semana ou não;

segue exemplo

```
 // If para validar se a hospedagem está em dia de semana
  if (data_entrada.getDay() >= 1 && data_saida.getDay() <= 5) {
    for (let index = data_entrada.getDate(); index < data_saida.getDate(); index++) {
      vSumDiasHospedagem++        
    };

    validaTaxaExtra = data_saida.getHours() + ':' + data_saida.getMinutes();

    if (validaTaxaExtra > '12:00') {
      vSumDiasHospedagem++
    }

    vSumTotal = vSumDiasHospedagem * 450;
    
  }
```

No else sigo a mesma lógica só passando os valores do fim de semana

Answer (score 0):

Portanto fazes um ciclo pelos dias e verificas se é dia de semana ou fim-de-semana para incrementar os respetivos contadores.

Depois verificas se passa do meio-dia e se é dia de semana ou fim-de-semana.

Por fim fazes a conta do total tendo em conta os preços à semana e ao fim-de-semana.

```
vSumDiasHospedagem = 0;
vSumDiasSemana = 0;
vSumDiasFimDeSemana = 0;
vSumTotal = 0;

let day = new Date(data_entrada);
while (day <= data_saida) {
    vSumDiasHospedagem++;
    var dt = new Date(day);
    if (dt.getDay() >= 1 && dt.getDay() <= 5) {
        vSumDiasSemana++;
    }
    else {
        vSumDiasFimDeSemana++;
    }

    let next_day = day.setDate(day.getDate() + 1);
    day = new Date(next_day);
}

validaTaxaExtra = data_saida.getHours() + ':' + data_saida.getMinutes();

if (validaTaxaExtra > '12:00') {
    vSumDiasHospedagem++;
    if (data_saida.getDay() >= 1 && data_saida.getDay() <= 5) {
        vSumDiasSemana++;
    }
    else {
        vSumDiasFimDeSemana++;
    }
}

vSumTotal = (vSumDiasSemana * 450) + (vSumDiasFimDeSemana * 600);
```

Comment: Vlw, foi resolvido